# Algorithm or pseudo code for finding combinations from table

Tags: database, algorithm

I have a table with thousands of items with a lot of attributes (approx 15+). I would like to select the following results:

1. Select all combination of items to have at least 100% from each attributes? Exactly 100% would be nice but thats not necessary so it can go over a little or be a little less (maybe +-2%).
2. All combinations would be a big dataset so I think it would be better to sort them by price and select only the 10 cheapest one.
3. Also if I would like to modify selects before so that one or several attributes cant get over some value, like 50% for example?

```
| ----------- | ------------ | ----------- | ----------- | ----- |
|  item name  |  attribute 1 | attribute 2 | attribute 3 | price |
|   item 1    |     25%      |     1%      |     5%      |   1€  |
|   item 2    |     10%      |    10%      |    10%      |   2€  |
|   item 3    |      5%      |    20%      |     5%      |   3€  |
|   item 4    |     20%      |    15%      |    50%      |  12€  |
```

I don't know if there is an existing algorithm for my problem ( I hope so ) or my problem has a name I can google but I would be thankful for any tips how I should proceed.

The only way I could think of for now is to bruteforce all the combinations and drop the unusable ones. But I don't think that's the right way (maybe I'm wrong and thats the only way).

The number of items, price and attribute values can change over time. If they were static I would just run the bruteforce option once and be done with it.

Sorry if this question was already asked.

EDIT:

As an example I can provide nutritional information about food (All the numbers are made up):

daily intake of carbohydrates/fat/protein are 225g/30g/65g

```
| ----------- | --------------- | ------- | --------- | ------ | ----- |
|  item name  |  carbohydrates  |   fat   |  protein  | sodium | price |
|    apple    |       10g       |   1g    |    5g     |   1mg  |   1€  |
|    banana   |       20g       |   2g    |   10g     |   1mg  |   2€  |
|    pear     |       15g       |   3g    |    5g     |   5mg  |   3€  |
| ----------- | --------------- | ------- | --------- | ------ | ----- |
```

1. find me combination of foods which will reach daily intake.
2. Now i want the same as in 1. but sort it by the price/select the cheapest.
3. I want only combinations with sodium not exceeding 30mg

Comment: Google `knapsack problem`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - could you post sample data and expected results, showing which results you _do_ want, and which you _don't_, and why?

Comment: I edited my question with an example. I hope it will be clear now.